How can I prepopulate the 'To' address to a record lookup on a custom email action?
I know we can pre populate the 'To' address to be an email address. But I was wondering if there is a way to do the same for a Contact relationship.
When I configure the Email Action as shown here:

It populates the email only:

This is what I need to do so that Email Templates still work:

Is there a way to automate this?

To achieve this you need to use To Recipients and prepopulate it with a id.

It will populate the record as you wanted:-

